# How to launch a Fragment from within Jetpack Compose with Fragment Manager?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-jetpack-compose

The problem is how to get the proper activity context to launch to get the Fragment Manager?
From interoperability between Composables and Fragment point of view is this even possible?

```
   @Keep
    class Card @JvmOverloads constructor(
        context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null
    ) : FrameLayout( // or any other View you want
        // don't forget to use context wrapper and to apply your own theme
        ContextThemeWrapper(
            context,
            context.resources.newTheme().apply { applyStyle(R.style.FantasyTheme, true) }
        ),
        attrs
    ), GamingHubView {
    
        override fun initialize(data: Map<String, Any>?) {
            // inflate a view or render views dynamically
    //        inflate(context, R.layout.view_card, this)
    
    
            val transaction: FragmentTransaction =
                (this.context as AppCompatActivity).supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            transaction.replace(
                this.id,
                BlankFragment.newInstance("", ""),
                BlankFragment::class.simpleName
            )
            transaction.addToBackStack(null)
            transaction.commit()
        }
    
    
    }
    
    /**
     * Get activity instance from desired context.
     */
    fun getActivity(context: Context?): AppCompatActivity? {
        if (context == null) return null
        if (context is AppCompatActivity) return context
        return if (context is ContextWrapper) getActivity(context.baseContext) else null
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get activity in compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64675386/how-to-get-activity-in-compose)

Comment: If you're running `setContent` from a Fragment, you can get it in the same way prior the activity.

Comment: Not sure, the class is an overload of Composable & not even compose so I think my question itself is wrong

Comment: Mostly avoid using context of any form in composable and supply handling classes as params...

Comment: This might address your question https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/load-fragments-in-jetpack-compose-beyond-what-google-taught-356a7981268d?sk=43b363c34040c646454d1629ef5f504b

Answer (score 4):

You can get a reference to the activity from within a compose function with this line:

```
val activity = LocalContext.current as? AppCompatActivity ?: return
```

Then you can get the support fragment manager and do fragment transactions from within your compose code.

```
activity.supportFragmentManager.commit {
    ...
}
```

I think this is not in the full spirit of compose but if you have a hybrid fragment/compose app then I don't see the harm in doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I have searched for this everywhere but I couldn't find that specific answer. I guess what you are trying to do is combine compose and fragment. What I did in my case was created a MyActivity with a compose view that fills the entire screen like this

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MyActivity">

    <androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView
        android:id="@+id/compose_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Then in MyActivity onCreate method, you instantiate your compose view like this

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_capture)

        findViewById<ComposeView>(R.id.compose_view).setContent {
            **YourTheme** {

            }
        }
    }
```

Then anywhere in your activity, you have access to `supportFragmentManager` that you can use to perform fragment transactions. All compose function will be done within the `composeView.setContent {  }`