# Compose creating new ViewModel instance

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel

I work in a project that's slowly adopting Jetpack Compose. It's mostly a single `Activity` multiple `Fragment`s app where we use the Android's navigation component to handle transitions to each screen (`Fragment`). Whenever we can, we are only replacing the `Fragment`s' XML layout with Composables.

The cases up until now were handling like the following:

**A. `Fragment`s show composables and handle navigation:**

```
class ScreenFragment : Fragment() {

    // For observing events that trigger navigation
    private val viewModel by lazyViewModel { ScreenViewModel() }

    override fun onCreateView( ... ): View {
        return ComposeView(requireContext()).apply {

            setViewCompositionStrategy(DisposeOnLifecycleDestroyed(viewLifecycleOwner))

            setContent {
                AppTheme {
                    Screen(onBackPressed = { findNavController().navigateUp() })
                }
            }
        }
    }    
    ...

}
```

**B. Composable that handles everything else UI related:**

```
@Composable
fun CreatePassword(
    onBackPressed: () -> Unit,
) {

    // For observing UI states and events
    val viewModel: CreatePasswordViewModel = viewModel()
    ...
}
```

As you can see, we have a reference for the screen's `ViewModel` in both our `Fragment`s and our Composables. Up until now, this has been working fine, the composable `viewModel()` function was always returning the same existing instance of the `Fragment`'s `ViewModel`.

The problems came when we needed the reference of a `ViewModel` scoped to an `Activity` on the composable:

1. We create the `ViewModel` on the `Activity`:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val viewModel by lazyViewModel { MainViewModel() }
    ...
}
```

2. Get a reference for the `MainActivity`'s `ViewModel` on the `Fragment` like

```
class MainFragment : Fragment() {

    private val viewModel: MainViewModel by viewModels(::requireActivity)
    ...
}
```

3. We get the reference of the ViewModel for composables as shown above (item B)

By doing so the `Fragment` has the same instance of the `Activity`'s but the composable doesn't.

My questions is,
**would it be possible to get the reference of the `Activity`'s `ViewModel` inside the composable?** For now I'm simply passing down the `Fragment`'s `ViewModel` as a parameter to my main composable screen.

Comment: `viewModel()` takes a `ViewModelStoreOwner` as a parameter that controls the scope of that ViewModel, just like your `lazyViewModel`. If you want to scope a ViewModel to your activity, why aren't you passing in your activity to `viewModel()`?

Comment: why you don't pass the viewmodel as an argument to CreatePassword composble ?

Comment: @ianhanniballake, I tried passing my `Activity` to `viewModel()` but I ended up getting a new instance of the viewModel too. 

I was getting my `Activity` as done here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68423182/8189765

Comment: @MobinYardim That's exactly what I'm doing now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to pass down the `Activity`'s `ViewModel` by providing a `ViewModelStoreOwner` to my composable as following:

```
class ScreenFragment : Fragment() {

    // For observing events that trigger navigation
    private val viewModel by lazyViewModel { ScreenViewModel() }

    override fun onCreateView( ... ): View {
        return ComposeView(requireContext()).apply {

            setViewCompositionStrategy(DisposeOnLifecycleDestroyed(viewLifecycleOwner))

            setContent {
                val viewModelStoreOwner =
                    compositionLocalOf<ViewModelStoreOwner> { requireActivity() }
    
                AppTheme {
                    CompositionLocalProvider(
                        LocalViewModelStoreOwner provides viewModelStoreOwner.current
                    ) {
                        Screen(onBackPressed = { findNavController().navigateUp() })
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }    
    ...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a classic dependency problem, at this point I would consider using some sort of Dependency Injection library and make sure to provide the `viewModel` instance as a singleton.

I can recommend Koin:
https://insert-koin.io/

Or, more recently and trendy Hilt:
https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android

Once using a good DI you can get an instance of the `viewModel` in your compose functions.