# Revenue Cat Jetpack Compose Purchase Package

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, revenuecat

I'm trying to purchase a packages using the Revenue Cat SDK under JetPack Compose.

The SDK provides a function called `PurchasePackage()` (and `PurchasePackageWith()`) but all of these function's signatures require an `Activity` which I do not know how to obtain from an `@Composable`.

I've tried this answer from S.O. https://stackoverflow.com/a/68423182/695524 but that gives my `null` as the Activity.

What does work is: `val activity = LocalContext.current as Activity` but, according to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65243835/695524 that is potentially unsafe to user in production code.

So, how to safely obtain an `Activity` from Jetpack compose so I can Purchase a Package using the Revenue Cat SDK?

Comment: The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68423182/695524) is correct, just replace `AppCompatActivity` with subclass of your activity, it may be `ComponentActivity` instead of `AppCompatActivity`, or something else.

Comment: I mean superclass, not subclass. Or you just can use `Activity` instead

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot Pylyp Dukov

Thanks to your comment, I've changed the solution to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68423182/695524 as folows:

```
fun Context.getActivity(): Activity? = when (this) {
    is AppCompatActivity -> this
    is ComponentActivity -> this
    is Activity -> this
    is ContextWrapper -> baseContext.getActivity()

    else -> null
}
```

Now, from an `@Composable` function, I'm able to get the/an `Activity` like this:

`val activity = LocalContext.current.getActivity()`

And now I'm able to complete a purchase with Revenue Cat.