# Show DialogFragment inside Compose Activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-fragmentactivity, android-dialogfragment

I have an Activity that extends *ComponentActivity* (Activity variant that is used for Compose based Activity Implementation), **thus have no access to FragmentManager**.

**Is there any way to show DialogFragment(implemented with View System) in it ?**

```
class MyActivity : ComponentActivity(){

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {
    //how to show DialogFragment here? there is no access to FragmentManager
        ScreenContent()
    }
}
}
```

Comment: There is  a Context available in Compose, but there is no access to FragmentManager(or its newer variant, SupportFragmentManager)

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68423182/3585796) answer your question? Using activity you can get `FragmentManager`

Comment: no this is not the answer of my question, i want to show fragment with supportFragmentManager

Answer (score 3):

I reckon, you must use FragmentActivity instead of ComponentActivity. It is already extended from ComponentActivity and supported for fragment manager. I have used it and it worked.

For instance;

```
class MyActivity : FragmentActivity(){

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {
        val dialogFragment = CustomDialogFragment.newInstance() // DialogFragment
        dialogFragment.show(supportFragmentManager, "Your classname")
        ScreenContent()
    }
}
}
```