# ViewModel Structure not maintaining variable values when called in seperate Jetpack Compose Composables

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel

In the `DiscoverCountries` composable page, there is a button composable that updates the value of the `selectedContinent` string member of the `ContinentsViewModel` ViewModel() class. I am trying to use the updated string in a different composable function in a different file, but the default empty string is being maintained.

When this specific button is clicked, it passes the `viewModel1.selectContinent("North America")` function to execute, changing the value of the string in the viewmodel.

```
class ContinentsViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val selectedContinent: MutableState<String> = mutableStateOf("")

    fun selectContinent(continent: String) {
        selectedContinent.value = continent
        Log.d("ViewModel", "Continent selected: $continent")

    }
}
```

```
item(){
                    val pdeCard3 = Card("Some Title", "Some Location", 123)
                    pdeCard3.ContinentsCard(navController,
                        "North America",
                        onContinentSelected = { viewModel1.selectContinent("North America") })
                }
```

Here is the relevant code snippet for the function definition:

```
    @Composable
    fun ContinentsCard(navController: NavHostController, continentName: String, onContinentSelected: () -> Unit) {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(67.dp)
                .clickable{
                    onContinentSelected()
                    navController.navigate(ScreenView.ContinentsCountriesPage.route)
                }
```

The button does correctly navigate to the `ContinentsCountriesPage`, but the "North America" string in the viewmodel is not maintained, it is seen as an empty string from the destination composable.

```
@Composable
fun ContinentsCountriesPage(navController: NavHostController){
    Log.d("ViewModelTest", "Page Opened")

    val viewModel1: ContinentsViewModel = viewModel()
    val selectedContinent = viewModel1.selectedContinent.value
    Log.d("ViewModel", "Continent selected: $selectedContinent")
    Log.d("ViewModelTest", "ContinentsCountries ViewModel: ${viewModel1.hashCode()}")
```

I have tried console logging the value of the `selectedContinent`, the value is correctly being updated in the `DiscoverCountries` code file, but an empty string in  the `ContinentsCountriesPage` file. I have ensured the views are under the same Navigation Host controller. When logging the hashCode of the viewmodels in each file, they are different, I'm not sure if they are supposed to be the same hashCode.

Comment: well, is it the same _instance_ of the viewmodel or a new one ?

Answer (score 0):

You may consider passing the string as a navigation argument as described here: [Navigate with arguments](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#nav-with-args).

Or you can create an app level `ViewModel`. To do so, you can pass your `ComponentActivity` as a `ViewModelStoreOwner` to `viewModel` function. To find the parent activity you can use this function ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68423182)):

```
fun Context.findActivity(): ComponentActivity? = when (this) {
    is ComponentActivity -> this
    is ContextWrapper -> baseContext.findActivity()
    else -> null
}

val appViewModel: AppViewModel = viewModel(LocalContext.current.findActivity()!!)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your ViewModel class, try to replace this line:

```kotlin
    val selectedContinent: MutableState<String> = mutableStateOf("")
```

For this one:

```kotlin
    var selectedContinent: MutableState<String> = mutableStateOf("")
     private set
```

This means that your variable is only available for `read` outside the ViewModel, but `read & write` inside ViewModel.