# How to get the activity so I can pass it to a function in androidStudio?

Tags: kotlin, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

I followed a tutorial on youtube to get the location. It worked well, but I tried to changed it into a function so I can use it in app that uses navcontroller and now it is asking for an activity and I tried to pass the screen it is called in but i get an error. What must I pass as a parameter in the function so that it works? Here's my code

```
@Composable
fun LoginScreen(
    navController : NavController
) {

   
    val context = LocalContext.current

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        
        Button(onClick = {
                
            fetchLocation(context, this) <-----Here is the error. I tried Screens.Login and Login
```

Here is the function

```
private fun fetchLocation(context: Context, Login: Activity): MutableList<Double> {

    lateinit var fusedLocationProviderClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
    fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context)
    val task = fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation
    var coordinate: MutableList<Double> = mutableListOf()

    if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat
            .checkSelfPermission(context, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    ){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Login, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION), 101)
        //in requestPermissions, if I put context instead of Login I get told to put an activity
        return coordinate
    }
    task.addOnSuccessListener{
        if(it !=null) {
            coordinate.add(it.longitude)
            coordinate.add(it.latitude)


        }
    }
    return coordinate
}
```

Comment: Check permission before fetchLocation function with rememberPermissionState() in compose function (LoginScreen). After try take location info. More readable, more safely.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get activity in compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64675386/how-to-get-activity-in-compose)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do context as Activity

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(context as Activity, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION), 101)
return coordinate
```